# File system access from Safari (IOS)

Tags: java, iphone, ios, ipad, safari

For Windows/Linux based browsers I can use Java plugin to access filesystem. As IOS does not support Java, is there any alternative way to get it done?

Comment: That's not possible. Each app on iOS is sandboxed, so can't access the system or other app's files. Safari does support web storage, but not filesystem access... In iOS 6 you'll be able to access the user's photos through a standard `<input type='file'/>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. File cannot be uploaded or even downloaded in iOS safari. In iCab you can upload by `<input type = 'file'>` but you can't access filesystem. Acessing entire filesystem from browser will be a security disaster. And also java plugin can't acess entire filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you want to do. If you just want allow user to navigate to interesting file(s) and then upload it to server for processing you can use `<input type='file'>` in your HTML. If you need more functionality you have to implement native plug-in to browser or use Flash.

Comment: iOS doesn't support plugins of any kind, and definitely no flash, and no `<input type='file'/>` before iOS 6.